# Return dsply message from a rpgle pgm to a cl variable

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, cl, rpg

I have a cl program thats call rpgle program. The rpgle program produces a dsply "message"
I want to set the dsply message as a variable in the cl program used to call the rpgle pgm.

What cl command to retrieve the dsply message to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The `DSPLY` op-code sends a `Information` message...

Take a look at the Receive Message (RCVMSG) has mentioned in the [Receiving messages into a CL procedure or program](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=messages-receiving-into-cl-procedure-program) section of the CL Programming documentation.

Comment: I tried but cant get the hang of it. What parts of RCVMSG do i need to set so i can change a variable in the cl program by calling the rpgle program.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding here is that you're trying to change a variable within a CL program via a call to an RPG program.

Let's ignore DSPLY for now as my guess is that you don't actually need it.

Example CL program (MYCLPGM) that sets a variable to "Apple", calls an RPG program changing said variable to "Orange" and displays the resulting variable's value as a message in the job log (and in the message area on screen, depending on your emulator);

```
PGM                                                   
                                                      
DCL        VAR(&MYVAR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(10)            
                                                      
/* Change variable "&MYVAR" to "APPLE" */             
CHGVAR     VAR(&MYVAR) VALUE('APPLE')                 
                                                      
/* Call RPG program to change "&MYVAR" to "Orange" */ 
CALL       PGM(MYRPGPGM) PARM(&MYVAR)                 
                                                      
/* Send message to job log showing what &MYVAR now contains */
SNDPGMMSG  MSG('&MYVAR = ' || &MYVAR)                 
                                                      
ENDPGM
```

Example RPGLE program (MYRPGPGM) to change variable;

```
d MYRPGPGM        pr                  extpgm('MYRPGPGM')        
d   myVar                       10a                             
                                                                
d MYRPGPGM        pi                                            
d   myVar                       10a                              
                                                                
 /free                                                          
                                                                
   // Change passed in variable "myVar" from "Apple" to "Orange"
   myVar = 'Orange';                                            
                                                                
   // Return to caller                                          
   return;                                                      
                                                                
 /end-free
```